# Correct the classpath so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring and while running i am getting the following error.

I did try the solution of [Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540189/correct-the-classpath-of-your-application-so-that-it-contains-a-single-compatib) but still getting the error.

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-11 00:00:22,103 ERROR [restartedMain] org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.<init>(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:57)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.of(Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry;
```

The method's class, org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users//.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Users//.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry