# using eureka server in spring application, could not find different methods

Tags: netflix-eureka

I have a Gradle project where I try to start a Eureka Server.
Here is my Setup:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server:+'
    // compileOnly('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:+')
}
```

In this way I try to start the Application :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

But unfortunately some errors occurred:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>(java.lang.Object[])'
Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener and org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with your dependencies version. please look into a similar issue.
[Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540189/correct-the-classpath-of-your-application-so-that-it-contains-a-single-compatib)

possible to share build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
I found the solution. I updated my dependencies in this way :

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:+'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:+'
```

}